# How to download formatted HTML data in XLXS or other format which can open in latest MAC

Tags: php, excel, xlsx

I can download .xls file but not able to download .XLXS file with the below code.

```
    $file = 'XLSOUTPUT'.date('Y-m-d').'.xlx';
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

$OFObj->action = 'xls';
$OFObj->opt = $_REQUEST['opt'];
$_POST['opt'] = $_REQUEST['opt'];
$_POST['IDS'] = $_REQUEST['IDS'];
$_POST['actionFor'] = $_REQUEST['actionFor'];
$_POST['OrderId'] = $_REQUEST['OrderId'];
$htmlData = $OFObj->___generateOutputsPrint();
echo $htmlData;
```

Comment: Change format to xlxs?

Comment: You would also want to change your header for the content type. I believe to this: header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

Comment: Simone Rossaini, I tried this but it is showing broken file after download.